# durandal.router isNavigating property weird error

Tags: durandal, durandal-navigation

I use durandal router to show a spinning icon while the page is loading. This is the code that makes it appear or hide itself:

```
<div data-bind="css: { activeLoader: router.isNavigating }" class="pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>
```

However, I want to put it inside my nav, like this:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
        <li>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, css: { active: isActive }, html: caption"></a>
            <i data-bind="css: { activeLoader: router.isNavigating }" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin pull-right"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This throws the message "**router is not defined**" inside chrome's developer tools console window.

But if I use the first snippet above, everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are inside the forEach binding. The scope inside the forEach binding will be a `route` since you are iterating through the `visibleRoutes`. What you can do is to use `$parent` to access parent viewModel like this,

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
        <li>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, css: { active: isActive }, html: caption"></a>
            <i data-bind="css: { activeLoader: $parent.router.isNavigating }" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin pull-right"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Read more on [binding contexts in KO](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)